# I am trying to display the keyName , pattern of Keyless and Keypresent array of Objects in angular js but it is not working

Tags: angular, angular8

```
let data = {
  headerFields: {
    keyLess: [{
      key1: {
        name: "test1"
      },
      key2: {
        name: "test2"
      },
      key3: {
        name: "test3"
      }
    }],
    keyPresent: [{
      key1: {
        name: "test4"
      }
    }]
  },
}
```

I have tried code something like

```
<tr *ngFor="let list of Data.keyLess; let num = index;">
     <td>{{num+1}}</td> 
      <td>{{'key'+ [num+1]}}</td>
      <td>Header</td>
      <td>{{'list' + '.'+'key'+[num+1]+ '.keyName'}}</td> 

 </tr>
```

**Num** variable is using as key index when I write {{list.key1.keyName}} then I get the output but it will print only first row. How Can I list out all the keyName with using "num"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<tr *ngFor="let list of data.keyLess; let num = index;">
 <td>{{num+1}}</td> 
  <td>{{'key'+ [num+1]}}</td>
  <td>Header</td>
  <td>{{list['key'+(num+1)].name}}</td> 

</tr>
```